# What was this crackdown about in Moscow, Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, police

- [You Won't Believe Who's Funding Quran Burning Stunts](https://youtu.be/WDycJ_gaVQI)

In the above YouTube video at 03:49, some Russian heavily armed Russian policemen are seen raiding a mosque in Moscow. They are rounding up the people praying there.

What was this raid about? What was the issue with the people in the mosque?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is footage of OMON/Rosgvardiya unit raiding an illegal house of prayer in Kotel'niki, a town just outside Moscow notorious for having one of the largest malls in the area as well as predominantly immigrant population.

It did spark a lot of controversy in Russia. Muslim community insist that police should not storm houses of prayer like that. Core population of the region cites expresses safety concerns WRT ghettoization of some towns.

**Update:** Finally got to see the video. The claim of this video, that the raid was to mobilize those muslim immigrants into armed forces and send them to Ukraine, is factually false.

Comment: why do the immigrants run illegal houses of prayer?

Comment: A combination of them not being content with existing prayer options, and the reluctance of the general public to expand these options.

Comment: @user366312 - A much better question would be "Why is the government outlawing houses of prayer?"

Comment: _notorious for having one of the largest malls in the area_ . Does mall mean something other than shopping mall in this context? Why would having a large mall make it notorious?

Comment: @T.E.D. Because certain branches of certain religions are very closely tied to independence movements/terrorist organisations. Relations between Moscow and the eastern Caucasus remain very strained.

Comment: @RedBaron Retail is a large employer of immigrant labor, so you would expect them living around large malls.

Answer (score 0):

The video shows OMON police entering the multi-storey building, clearly not  intended for praying. A formal reason of the intrusion can be trivial violation of the fire safety regulations, as we see many people in a very confined and difficult to escape place.

It is not clear if these people are not allowed, cannot afford or not willing to build or rent a more appropriate place for praying. As video only shows internals of the building, the location is also very difficult to tell.